# Finding "free" inside libc.so

Tags: linux, shared-object

I extracted the libc.so.6 from within a vulnerable image used for exploitation purposes. I open up the shared object in IDA and I look at the symbols inside the "Exports" tab. I find "free"; upon visiting the function however, its body seems to do something rather different from what I'd expect from a dlmalloc free implementation. What am I missing?

Comment: Are there any version symbols in your libc.so? Maybe you're not dealing with the standard glibc, but a very old version, or µlibc, or even a version that has custom implementations of some functions, trading memory footprint for speed, or vice versa.

Comment: The machine has a dynamically compiled binary that has a vulnerable binary(that can be exploited due to how dlmalloc works). ldd shows that the binary depends on this shared object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out why this problem happens. However, I just dumped "free" from within gdb, opened it up in IDA and it works just fine.